# Service Fabric doesn't published application if LoadMetric is specified in ServiceManifest.xml

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I have specified in ServiceManifest.xml the LoadMetric CommunicationCount:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceManifest Name="StatelessWcfNetPkg"
                 Version="1.0.0"
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2011/01/fabric"
                 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <ServiceTypes>
    <StatelessServiceType ServiceTypeName="StatelessWcfNetType" >
      <LoadMetrics>
        <LoadMetric Name="ConnectionCount" DefaultLoad="1" SecondaryDefaultLoad="1" Weight="High"/>
      </LoadMetrics>
    </StatelessServiceType>
  </ServiceTypes>

  <CodePackage Name="Code" Version="1.0.0">
    <EntryPoint>
      <ExeHost>
        <Program>StatelessWcfNet.exe</Program>
      </ExeHost>
    </EntryPoint>
  </CodePackage>

  <ConfigPackage Name="Config" Version="1.0.0" />

  <Resources>
    <Endpoints>
      <Endpoint Name="ServiceEndpoint" />
    </Endpoints>
  </Resources>
</ServiceManifest>
```

It was built, but by publish I had an error:

```
4>Creating application...
4>New-ServiceFabricApplication : An error occurred during this operation.  Please check the trace logs for more details.
4>In C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service 
4>Fabric\Tools\PSModule\ServiceFabricSDK\Publish-NewServiceFabricApplication.ps1:358 Zeichen:9
4>+         New-ServiceFabricApplication -ApplicationName $ApplicationNam ...
4>+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
4>    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Microsoft.Servi...usterConnection:ClusterConnection) [New-ServiceFabr 
4>   icApplication], FabricException
4>    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateApplicationInstanceErrorId,Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Powershell.NewApplication
4>
```

Without LoadMetric-tag, everything is fine. What doing I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The value of SecondaryDefaultLoad must be 0 or it shouldn't be appeared. I don't know why...